# How to parse a tfds.features.Sequence object ? It is not compatible with tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

Recently I was trying to train a model on the Wider-Face Dataset. I found it is prebuilt into tfds (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/wider_face). However I am having difficulty parsing it. It's feature map is of the following form -

```
FeaturesDict({
'faces': Sequence({
    'bbox': BBoxFeature(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32),
    'blur': tf.uint8,
    'expression': tf.bool,
    'illumination': tf.bool,
    'invalid': tf.bool,
    'occlusion': tf.uint8,
    'pose': tf.bool,
}),
'image': Image(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
'image/filename': Text(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),})
```

So I passed the following nested dictionary to tf.io.parse_single_example

```
feature_description = {'faces': {
    'bbox': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32),
    'blur': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.uint8),
    'expression': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.bool),
    'illumination': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.bool),
    'invalid': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.bool),
    'occlusion': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.uint8),
    'pose': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.bool),
},
'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.uint8),
'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),}
```

But it gives me a value error of ValueError: Unsupported dict. Later I also learnt that Sequence does not support features which are of type tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature.

Please let me know how can I parse this type of TFRecords. I didn't find much documentation of how to use the object detection datasets that are build into Tensorflow, so providing some links with examples will also be helpful.

Thanks